# populate pl/SQLvariable

Tags: plsql

I have the following

```
if hero.name != lastManStanding then
    dbms_output.put(hero.name);
    lastManStanding := hero.name;
end if;
```

where

```
lastManStanding hero.name%type;
```

However the if block never gets execute. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *lastManStanding* is null, the condition will never evaluate to true. Such is the case with *NULL*.

Change it to:

```
if hero.name != nvl(lastManStanding, 'xxxxxx') then
```